# BeautifulSoup not picking up text from span class or section class tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags, html-parsing, textblob

I am having difficulties printing out the text from this page as BeautifulSoup is not picking up the span class or section class tags. I would like to pull in the text from Motley Fool and then parse by sentence.

https://www.fool.com/earnings/call-transcripts/2019/04/26/exxon-mobil-corp-xom-q1-2019-earnings-conference-c.aspx

So far when it occasionally does pull in the text the sentence parsing works, however, beautiful soup only occasionally pulls in the text.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import re
def news(): 
    # the target we want to open     
    url = dataframe_url

    #open with GET method 
    resp=requests.get(url) 

    #http_respone 200 means OK status 
    if resp.status_code==200: 

        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"html.parser")

        #l = soup.find("span",attrs={'class':"article-content"})
        l = soup.find("section",attrs={'class':"usmf-new article-body"})

        #print ('\n-----\n'.join(tokenizer.tokenize(l.text)))
        textlist.extend(tokenizer.tokenize(l.text))

    else: 
        print("Error")
```

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples of sentences which are not being pulled? Also, did you try `soup.find_all()` instead of `soup.find()`?

Comment: I am trying to pull in the entire transcript text from the url, here is an example sentence in html: <p>Good day, everyone. Welcome to the ExxonMobil Corporation First Quarter 2019 Earnings Call. Today's call is being recorded.</p>

Answer (score 0):

In order to capture the transcript, you can try something like this - and modify to suit your needs:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.get('https://www.fool.com/earnings/call-transcripts/2019/04/26/exxon-mobil-corp-xom-q1-2019-earnings-conference-c.aspx')

soup = bs(response.content, 'lxml')

heads = soup.find_all('h2')
selections = ['Prepared Remarks:','Questions and Answers:']

for selection in selections:
    for head in heads:
        if head.text == selection:
            for elem in head.findAllNext():
                if elem.name != 'script':                    
                    print(elem.text)
                if 'Duration' in elem.text:
                    break
```

Let me know if it's close enough.

Comment: I appreciate the help I actually figured out that Motley Fool blacklisted my IP as I got a Max Retries SSL Error. I guess they really don't like web scraping as I've had similar errors in the past!